# Searching using a list of IDs in DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have a list with IDs that are selected by the user.
What is the best way to search all rows using this list of IDs in DBIx::Class??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
$rs->search({ 
    whatever_the_column_is => { 
        '=' => [ @a_bunch_of_ids ]
    }
})
```

or

```
$rs->search({
    whatever_the_column_is => {
       -in => [ @a_bunch_of_ids ]
    }
})
```

if your DB likes `IN` queries better. Both are documented in [SQL::Abstract docs](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/SQL-Abstract-1.72/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm#WHERE_CLAUSES).

Comment: Those are fine but a bit verbose. `$rs->search({ whatever_the_column_is => \@a_bunch_of_ids })` will do too.